# Parent list item onclick is taking over sub list item's onclick (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following partial template

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in alist" ng-click="toggleShowItems(a)">
        {{a.name}}
        <ul ng-if="a.showItems" >
            <li ng-repeat="item in a.items" ng-click="showItemDetail(item.id)"> {{item.id}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The problem I am having is that when I click on a item of the nested list, it collapses.  But what I really need is to have a different onclick action for the nested list items. Please let me know where I got it wrong.  Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your inner click just add `$event.stopPropagation()`

```
ng-click="showItemDetail(item.id);$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the click is bubbling up the dom tree. This can be stopped by passing the $event object as a parameter to the click and calling stopPropagation in the click handler:

View:

```
ng-click="showItemDetail(item.id, $event)"
```

Controller:

```
$scope.showItemDetail = function(id, $event){
    // do your stuff
    $event.stopPropagation();
};
```